# InstallShield prerequisites dialog appearence time

Tags: installshield-2011

I have an InstallScript setup created with IS 2011, which includes prerequisites: The prerequisites dialog immediately appears after executing setup.exe even before the welcome dialog.

Is there a way to change this behavior so that the prerequisites are installed at a later step during the setup e.g. when the real setup procedure is started (i.e. after the welcome dialog, license agreement, ...).
Also I want to avoid the prerequisites installation when my application is already installed and I execute setup.exe and choose the uninstall option.

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield offers a scheduling for prerequisites that is kicked off after the Install button. This approach is called "Feature Prerequisites" in the InstallShield help. Do be aware that since the .msi is already running, it is a more complicated time, so certain prerequisites should not be scheduled there (and others may fail to serve their purpose if installed after the wizard panels).

In InstallShield 2012 and later, the suite project type supports installing multiple packages after a single wizard. In that model, prerequisites are just another package, and your use case is more directly supported.